# ASP.NET Core routing based on body

Tags: asp.net-core, routes

The question is: can I have two controller methods that handle one endpoint based on the deserialized body (from XML)?
And if it's possible then how?

Example of what I want to have:

```
[HttpPost("products")]
public ActionResult AddProductA([FromBody] ProductA product) {}

[HttpPost("products")]
public ActionResult AddProductB([FromBody] ProductB product) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider using custom middleware to achieve your requirement.

You could check the request body firstly and then modify the request path to productA or productB.

Notice: Since the request body is stream, we could only read once. If we want to read multiple times, we should enable the request buffer.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

Statup.cs configure method:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }


    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {

        if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("products"))
        {
            context.Request.EnableBuffering();

            // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(
                context.Request.Body,
                encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
                detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
                bufferSize: 1024,
                leaveOpen: true))
            {
                var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

                if (body.Contains("</ProductA>"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/weatherforecast/productA";
                }

                if (body.Contains("</ProductB>"))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/weatherforecast/productB";
                }



                context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            }

        }

        await next();

    });

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();




    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
}
```

Controller action:

```
    [HttpPost("productA")]
    public ActionResult AddProductA([FromBody] ProductA product) {

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpPost("productB")]
    public ActionResult AddProductB([FromBody] ProductB product)
    {

        return Ok();
    }
```

Result:

We send different xml body to the same url and it goes to different action:

ProductA:

[image]

ProductB:

[image]

Comment: thanks for such a well-documented tip!
This is so much more straightforward to do than wrapping one's head around IHttpActionSelector mechanics